Convergence in $L^2$ of discretizations of a sequence
Let $u_n, u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, $\Omega$ being an open bounded of $R^n$. Suppose that $u_n \to u$ weakly in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ and strongly in $L^2$.
Now consider the following discretizazion of $u_j$. Let $\delta_j>0$ a descreasing sequence converging to zero, and, for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, let $Q_i^{\delta_j}$ be the cube centered in $\delta_j i$ and of volume $\delta_j^n$; we define $u_j^i$ as the average of $u_j$ on $Q_i^{\delta_j}$. We also define $Z_j= \{i\in \mathbb{Z}^n; \text{dist}(\delta_j i, \mathbb{R^n}\setminus\Omega) > \delta_j \}$ and set
$$
\psi_j = \sum_{i \in Z_j} u_j^i \chi_{Q_i^{\delta_j}},
$$
where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$. It is easily shown that $\psi_j \to u$ in $L^2$, indeed
\begin{equation}
\int_{Q_i^{\delta_j}}  |u_j -\psi_j|^2 =
 \int_{Q_i^{\delta_j}} |u_j-u_j^i|^2 \le 
c({Q_i^{\delta_j}} )\int_{Q_i^{\delta_j}}  |\nabla u_j|^2 \le
c \delta_j^2\int_{Q_i^{\delta_j}} |\nabla u_j|^2,
\end{equation}
where the first inequality is simply Poincaré-Wirtinger; hence summing in $i$ we get
$$
\int_{\Omega} |u_j -\psi_j|^2 \le
c \delta_j^2\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u_j|^2 \le c \delta_j^2\sup_j \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u_j|^2.
$$
Now the question is the following: considering $\tilde{u}_j^i$ be the average of $u_j$ on a sphere whose radium is $\delta_j^{\frac{n}{n-2}}$, contained in $Q_i^{\delta_j}$ and centered in $\delta_j i$; if we set
$$
\tilde{\psi}_j= \sum_{i \in Z_j} \tilde{u}_j^i \chi_{Q_i^{\delta_j}}
$$
is it true that $\tilde{\psi}_j$ converge to $u$ in $L^2$? Is it true in the possibly simplifing assumption that all $u_n$ and $u$ are in $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$?
